# What is the actual keysym for "<Control-->" in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a text editor using Python 3.7 and Tkinter. I'm having trouble on my keyboard shortcuts. Here is the code for the keyboard shortcuts:

```py
# Keyboard shortcuts
self.master.bind("<Control-o>", lambda key: self.open())
self.master.bind("<Control-O>", lambda key: self.open())
self.master.bind("<Control-s>", lambda key: self.save())
self.master.bind("<Control-S>", lambda key: self.save())
self.master.bind("<Control-Shift-s>", lambda key: self.saveas())
self.master.bind("<Control-Shift-S>", lambda key: self.saveas())
self.master.bind("<Control-q>", lambda key: self.quit())
self.master.bind("<Control-Q>", lambda key: self.quit())
self.master.bind("<Control-=>", lambda key: self.zoomIn())
self.master.bind("<Control-->", lambda key: self.zoomIn())
```

And here's the error I get when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "#############################################\TextPY\textpy.py", line 123, in <module>
    app = Application(master=root)
  File "#############################################\TextPY\textpy.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.master.bind("<Control-->", lambda key: self.zoomIn)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1251, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1206, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: no event type or button # or keysym
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line

```
self.master.bind("<Control-->", lambda key: self.zoomIn())
```

It should be

```
self.master.bind("<Control-minus>", lambda key: self.zoomIn())
```